# Running NPM install during Docker build in windows container

Tags: docker, docker-build, windows-container

I'm trying to run NPM install commands from within my Dockerfile during `docker build` in a windows container. The problem is that NPM cannot resolve the package registry and as a matter of fact no domain can be resolved because the DNS is not properly configured.

I tried running a `RUN` command in the Dockerfile to update the dns:
`RUN netsh interface ip set dns "Ethernet 2" static 8.8.8.8`
but it doesn't seem to work although the build finishes properly.

Is this even possible. Please note that I want to achieve this from within the Dockerfile during a docker build. Running a container with `--dns 8.8.8.8` works fine etc but that's not my goal.

EDIT: Adding sample Dockerfile

```
FROM randomimage:latest

COPY NodeDir C:/NodeDir
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
RUN .\node-vX.msi /quiet

# I also tried with SHELL ["netsh", "interface", "ip"], no luck
RUN netsh interface ip set dns "Ethernet 2" static 8.8.8.8
RUN npm i gulp -g
CMD cmd
```

Comment: could you share your dockerfile?

Comment: @Andrea added sample Dockerfile